# ¿Visualizar cualquier tipo de archivo mediante PHP?

Tags: php, php7

Existe la posibilidad de visualizar cualquier tipo de archivo **(Word, PDF, PowerPoint, Excel)** mediante código `PHP`?
Adjunto el código que tengo para visualizar un **PDF** en el navegador. El cual esta guardado en una base de Datos.

```
<?php
    $ruta = "upload/".$_GET['na']; // se obtiene la ruta del archivo en la carpeta Upload a través de la Variable enviada por URL
    if( !file_exists( $ruta ) ) { 
             die( "No existe $ruta" ); 
    } 

header("content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile($ruta);

?>
```

Me gustaría que se pudiera visualizar cualquier otro archivo.

Comment: Digo yo ... si para mostrar el `.pdf` dependes del navegador ... igual para mostrar otros también dependes del mismo. Incluso puede que dependas de que el equipo cliente tenga instalado un software capaz de leerlo.

Comment: Eh intentado tratar de abrir otros archivos tipo excel y word con el navegador y no los abre. Sólo intenta descargarlos.

Comment: Los archivos de Excel, Word, etc son de formato propietario por lo tanto el navegador no los va a visualizar de forma nativa sino que los descargará, por eso solo los puedes visualizar por ejemplo cuando estas en tu cuenta de Outlook por que la plataforma esta preparada para ello y forma parte del mismo dueño, dicho lo anterior *vas a requerir de plugins de terceros para lograr tu cometido*

Answer (score -1):

Si le pasas por get el tipo de formato por ejemplo ?formato=pdf o ? formato=xls, etc.
Despues en el codigo recuperas dicha variable y dependiendo del formato le pones una cabecera o otra. El problema que si una misma ruta quieres abrir diferentes archivos la cabecera cambian asi que seria algo asi.

```
$formato = $_GET["formato"];
switch($formato){
   case 'pdf':
    header("content-type: application/pdf");
    readfile($ruta);
    break;
   case 'xls':
    header("content-type: application/xls");
    readfile($ruta);
    break;
}
```

Podrias provarlo de esta manera, con diferentes headers haber si te funciona.